# Is there any way to get Graph API event reminder through subscription?

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We have multiple reminders like 5 minutes , 15 minutes and 30 minutes. We store them in our own database and send maximum time reminder with graph API create event using c# like 30 mins.
Now we want to achieve, on 30 min reminder notification we want our webhook to get hit so we can show reminder to user and update event with snooze reminder of 15 minutes.

Webhook is working fine on creating, updating and deleting of event but reminder time prompt is not hitting our webhook.

Is there any work around to subscribe event reminders ?

Answer (score 0):

Graph API calendar event resource type inherits from [event resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) that has a property `reminderMinutesBeforeStart`.
You can  [snooze](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-snoozereminder?view=graph-rest-1.0)  or  [dismiss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-dismissreminder?view=graph-rest-1.0)  a  [reminder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/reminder?view=graph-rest-1.0)  for  *user*  calendars only.
Please refer this [MS graph API multiple reminders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482951/ms-graph-api-multiple-reminders) SO thread for more information.